# Serial Data reading in matlab from ARM board

Tags: matlab

The program below is for reading serial data from ARM board into Matlab,

```
obj1 = serial('COM9');
set(obj1, 'InputBufferSize', 6000);
fopen(obj1); 
fprintf(obj1,'d');
Data = fscanf(obj1);
Data_num = str2num(Data);
fclose(obj1);
delete(obj1);
```

My situation is  - I am reading digital data (with 5 characters e.g. - 0.257). I set 'InputBufferSize' to 6000 to read 1000 data points because, if the size is not mentioned, it shows an error. It works well for 1000 digital data points.

Now, I want to read 2000 data points from ARM board and thus I doubled the 'InputBufferSize' to 12000 but `Data_num` only has 1600 data points. I even tried increasing the 'InputBufferSize', but this does not help.

Secondly I tried with each digital data with 4 characters, it increases the number of data points in 'Data_num' to some 1800, but not 2000. I want at least 5 characters in each data.